# How to create an image with any arbitrary number of channels? (Python)

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library, anaconda

I am working on a project in Python, Anaconda distro, and need to create and process images that have any arbitrary number of channels. For example, RGB has three channels

```
(R,G,B)
```

and I need to have any amount of user-defined channels, which could as many as 90 or so (which are actually elemental channels, from x-ray fluorescence data):

```
(Fe, P, K, S, Si, ...)
```

where each channel is simply a grayscale image (obviously).

So far I have been using the `PIL Image` module, and it works quite well except for this particular task. `PIL` does not support used defined image modes, and only has a select few modes to choose from, none of which go above 4 channels `(CMYK)`.

The documentation notes this very briefly, saying:

> However, PIL doesn’t support user-defined modes; if you to handle band combinations that are not listed above, use a sequence of Image objects.

This seems vague, and I'm not sure I would know exactly how to implement this. A sequence of Image objects? Meaning a sequence of objects, each of which do have a `PIL` supported image mode? Seems inefficient and ugly.

How can I accomplish this? Is there a package I can use other than `PIL`?

If it really comes down to it, I don't *need* to render an image, I can just use the "pixel" data for processing, but in the end it would still be nice to have an image as a result.

Comment: Hi, I would take a look to PIL implementation to see how they change the 3 vs 4 channels. hopefully the restriction is there only because it can't render more than four channels as an image.

Comment: Version 7 of ImageMagick is due to support an arbitrary number of channels in an image but it is not due till early next year...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple numpy arrays will be sufficient for you?

Comment: For the main purpose of my program, yes, the pixel data stored in an array is sufficient. It's just a matter of a better presentation of the results to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> With numpy you can store Images with multiple channels (here shown for
>   3 channels):

```
import numpy as np
num_channels = 3
random_image = np.random.randint(0,256, (300,400,num_channels))
```